# How to display HTML tags and copy it as plain text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display this command `echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>"` using `div` tag and copy it by pressing the `copy` button. I try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<div type="button" id="content">echo "<? phpinfo(); ?>"</div>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>

<script>
  function copyToClipboard() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText).then(() => {
    console.log(copyText);
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it only display `echo ""` and in console I see `echo "<!--? phpinfo(); ?-->"`

Then, I use entity number like this `echo "&#60? phpinfo(); ?&#62"` or entity name like this `echo "&lt;? phpinfo(); ?&gt;"` it displays correctly but when I press the `copy` button, I get the string with entity name or number which is not that I want.

How can I solve this?

Comment: textContent instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the tags in a `<pre>` tag, then they will display correctly, and also be fetched by the js correctly.

```
<div type="button"><pre id="content">echo "<? phpinfo(); ?>"</pre></div>
```